# Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons: Java Springboot run error after Springboot upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties, spring-boot-starter

[Find error img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWSmp.png)

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [3.1.6] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train
- Spring Cloud Sleuth is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

After upgrading to Springboot 3.1.6, am getting the above error in application. Properties. What shall I do?

Comment: If you are using Sprig Cloud you need to use a compatible version. So if you upgrade Spring Boot you also need to upgrade Spring Cloud. Which is also what the, quite clear, error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct spring cloud version.
The documentation lists which versions are compatible: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

2022.0.x aka Kilburn -> 3.0.x, 3.1.x (Starting with 2022.0.3)

Answer (score -3):

Add this in your application.properties file!

**spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false**

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue, only hides it.